# MVC How i can get id value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here Razor Code :

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<button type="button" class="ShowImages" data-toggle="modal" id="@item.ProductID" data-target="#myModal"  data-id=@item.ProductID onclick="fun_ShowImages()" >@Website.ShowImages</button>
}

function fun_ShowImages() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var htmlContents = " ";
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Products/ShowImage/" + id,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (response) {
               ...
                }
                htmlContents += '</table>';
                $('#ProductImages').html(htmlContents);
            },
            error: function (response) {
               ...
            }
        });
};
```

**strong text**
Here Error :

> **i need to know id attribute**
>       var id = $(this).attr("id"); // This give me undefine

Comment: What is $(this) ?

Comment: fun_ShowImages(e) {
        var id = $(e.currentTarget).attr("id");

Comment: i'm using this :
   $(".ShowImages").click({.......});
but give me first row only

Comment: Pass `this` context i.e. `onclick="fun_ShowImages.call(this)"`, rest of you code will work

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón thx u bro

Comment: @Satpal thx u too ^_^

Answer (score 3):

First, you should add quotation marks for `data-id` value:

```
<button type="button" class="ShowImages" data-toggle="modal" id="@item.ProductID" data-target="#myModal"  data-id="@item.ProductID" onclick="fun_ShowImages()" >@Website.ShowImages</button>
```

then you can use jQuery event handler `click`

E.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ShowImages").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id"); //or you can use data-id value
        //your logic...
    });
});
```

Or you can use `jQuery.on()`

```
$(document).on("click", ".ShowImages", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); //or you can use data-id value
    //your logic
});
```

Comment: this not work for me, im used this in first way but this give me only first row data ( first value )
with send object in fun that is work

Comment: @ZombieBot, in this situation you have to use only `on` method, because elements are added dynamically.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai, how do you know they are added dynamically? You can see only foreach loop, but nothing else. Foreach loop is done on server side, before response is send to client. DOM is loaded with complete list of buttons. Plus TS wrote that it worked, but it returned wrong ID, so event handler works...

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `this` is a reference to `window` object.

You can pass directly the `id` value as parameter.

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   <button type="button" class="ShowImages" data-toggle="modal"
   id="@item.ProductID" data-target="#myModal"  
   data-id=@item.ProductID onclick="fun_ShowImages(@item.ProductId)" >@Website.ShowImages</button>
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

function fun_ShowImages(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Products/ShowImage/" + id,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (response) {
               ...
                }
                htmlContents += '</table>';
                $('#ProductImages').html(htmlContents);
            },
            error: function (response) {
               ...
            }
        });
};
```

Another method is to attach a `click` event handler and use `$(this)` selector.

Also, in this situation you have to use `.on` method  for `event delegation`, especially for elements which were added **dynamically**.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

```
$(document).on("click", ".ShowImages", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); //or you can use data-id value
    var htmlContents = " ";
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Products/ShowImage/" + id,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (response) {
           ...
            }
            htmlContents += '</table>';
            $('#ProductImages').html(htmlContents);
        },
        error: function (response) {
           ...
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code `this` doesn't refers to element which invoke the event handler, it refers to `window` object. Thus you are getting the error.

You can use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to set the context

```
<button type="button"  onclick="fun_ShowImages.call(this)" >@Website.ShowImages</button>
```

```js
function fun_ShowImages() {
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="1" onclick="fun_ShowImages.call(this)">ShowImages</button>
```